# How to access the discussion already done in a chatroom again?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

Not very long ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902907/subformula-determining-using-two-definitions) and regarding that I tried to clear up my confusion of Mauro's answer [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44484/discussion-between-user-170039-and-mauro-allegranza). But now I can't access the room. How can I access the room again?

---

**Edit:** I can access the room again.

Comment: The room was auto-deleted for inactivity. Are you logged in on chat? Maybe if you are, you could still access it. I can access it, when logged in yet not otherwise. (This is not exactly the same situation though as being a mod on another site I have more options in chat than a regular user.) But still worth a try, log in on chat and try again. If it still fails, ask a moderator for example via a flag on the respective post to undelete and unfreeze it. (In this particular case you can also just ask me here.)

Comment: @quid: I can access other rooms but not this room.

Comment: I undeleted the room it should work now.

Comment: Some general advice about unfreezing rooms is given [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room).

Comment: It's great @MartinSleziak. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The room was auto-deleted for inactivity. [Inactive chatrooms are frozen](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) and if they do not contain much content they are even deleted (where as usual on SE 'deleted' just means soft-deleted).

A moderator can  undelete the room with one click. (Since it is chat a moderator on any SE site can do this, thus I did it.) It should then stay in that state for some days, but will be deleted again if there is no further activity.

As a general procedure I would propose to flag the post to which the chat is attached for moderator attention and ask to undelete the chat. If it is not attached to a particular post I would ask in the [Math Mod's office](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office).

Comment: Another reasonable alternative is [this room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2691/the-assembly), 
as advised here: [How do I unfreeze a frozen chat room?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room/70201#70201).